# Unable to access Bitnami Django web app using run server of mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I am not sure what I am missing here to get Django running on Google Compute Engine and access it publicly. I am starting with Django packaged by Bitnami since it seems like it would be easy...

I have been following this Getting Started Guide to get a running instance of Django running on Google Compute Engine.

[Django Packaged By Bitnami For Google Cloud Platform](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/get-started/get-started/#step-2-serve-your-application-through-the-apache-web-server)

It successfully deploys and I see the Bitnami page. I am unable to get pass this point even with the simple example of hello world in their guide. I have used both `./manage.py runserver` and serving through Apache Web server with the module `mod_wsgi` for my project.

> Test Your Django Project The Django project can be started by using
> this command from the /opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT directory, and it
> will run on port 8000:
>
> cd /opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT python manage.py runserver To access
> the application, browse to http://SERVER-IP:8000/. To end the
> application, terminate the running Django process.

I have completed a Django Project that I can test and run locally. Getting something basic on Google Compute Engine, is another story.

Comment: What is the actual problem? If you have started a python program (Django) listening on port 8000, then you must also create a VPC firewall rule allowing ingress on port 8000. However, I strongly recommend that you configure Django to run behind Apache. Limit your question to one configuration or the other, show the configuration, the method you are trying to access the instance, error messages, log file results, etc. Tip: I recommend not using Bitnami. Instead, follow a guide to configure Apache + Django + Python.

Comment: I was able to access the development server after configuring port 8000. Why would you recommend not using Bitnami? I had issues running Django on Google Compute Engine out of the box trying to add packages and configurations.

Comment: Bitnami uses a different convention for how systems are configured. That can cause problems if you have further problems because their setup does not match what is the norm. Bitnami is fine if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @John Hanley, you can also try to deploy to ***“Deployment manager"***. I tested it on my environment, it's working properly. And the VPC network port is automatically configured `tcp:443` & `tcp:80` to my *djangostack* instance.

You can also follow this step, how to step by step to deploy from Deployment Manager

1. Open your **GCP Account** > **Deployment Manager**
2. Click + **DEPLOY MARKETPLACE SOLUTION**
3. Search **Django** to **Marketplace** > Click **Django packaged by Bitnami** > **LAUNCH**
4. Configure Django instance as your requirements
5. Deploy

And also if you're not using the ***"Deployment Manager"***, you can create firewall rule from VPC network as per @John Hanley.